# App Store Connect Operation Error : "Invalid AdamId"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11

the issue in Xcode 11.1 that the distribute with Xcode always fail 
and i don't have option to uploaded with the application loader.

i try to use the Transporter app for distribute but the app crash and in the debug its work.[image]

Comment: Upvoted, because, well, after first thinking this was a typo (AdamId?) it clearly isn't. And where the answer by @Adis may well be correct (and I'm not saying he/she downvoted), anything called "AdamId" is seriously weird to this 4 year iOS app (and 35 year systems programming) developer.

Comment: Please login in itunesconnect and check the permission for the respective app.

Answer (score 0):

AdamId is your app id. It being invalid means you might be logged in with the wrong account / team, or, more likely, might not have the permissions to upload the binary.

Comment: i fix the issue, the issue for me was that i use the older account  of apple connect and the older account is older a lot of apps i just set other apple account as admin of all the apps in the users & access and login with this account inside the Xcode preference..

Answer (score 0):

i fix the issue, the issue for me was that i use the older account of apple connect and the older account is older a lot of apps i just set other apple account as admin of all the apps in the users & access and login with this account inside the Xcode preference..